# How to build AndEngine in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio, andengine

I wanted to build AndEngine and andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension from Anchor Center branch, but build failed.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':andEngine:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/mariusz/android/android-ndk/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-17 NDK_OUT=/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/lib APP_ABI=all
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    /home/mariusz/android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andengine_shared//home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/src/main/jni/src/GLES20Fix.o: in function Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glVertexAttribPointer:/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/src/main/jni/src/GLES20Fix.c:9: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
    /home/mariusz/android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andengine_shared//home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/src/main/jni/src/GLES20Fix.o: in function Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glDrawElements:/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/src/main/jni/src/GLES20Fix.c:13: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [/home/mariusz/Downloads/AndEngineApp/andEngine/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libandengine_shared.so] Error 1
```

I'm using Android Studio version 0.86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar/duplicate problem here [same error post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595344/andengine-android-studio-linker-error-during-build). It may help you. There is also a linked blog. It describes setup steps clearly. I am providing the link [here](http://handyandroidsnippets.blogspot.com/2014/07/android-studio-and-andengine-setup.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

I created a repository with a boilerplate AndEngine + Box2d for Android Studio config (as of AS version 1.0 RC). https://github.com/mutexkid/andengine-androidstudio . Tested on OSX 10.10.